# Swift Spritekit Collision Handling

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision

This is my first attempt with SpriteKit and I'm having trouble getting my collision right with bitmasks.
I have three categories, If player hits lit, I want to increase the score and move the lit node off screen, else, I want to call my gameover() function. I've tried a lot of variations and can't see to get anything but general collision to be recognized. I've defined the category and contact bitmasks for each node as well.

```
let playerCategory: UInt32 = 1
let razzCategory: UInt32 = 2
let litCategory: UInt32 = 4
```

---

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody


    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

    }

    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) == 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & litCategory) == 1)
    {
        lit.position.x = 400
        score += 1
    }
    else {
        gameOver()
    }

}
```

Comment: you do not want the if condition to equal 0 and 1, you want them to equal the category you are checking

Comment: id didBeginContact called at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) == 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & litCategory) == 1)` Translates to the following in english.

If Firstbody  AND playerCategory = 0 AND SecondBody And litCategory = 1

If Firstbody AND 1 = 0 AND SecondBody And 4 = 1

Now let's define Firstbody as playerCategory and SecondBody as litCategory

If playerCategory AND playerCategory = 0 AND litCategory and litCategory = 1

If 1 AND 1 = 0 AND 4 AND 4 = 1

If 1 = 0 AND 4 = 1

As you can see, this fails, and this method is always going to fail because if the second half of your test (SecondBody AND litCategory) can only have a value of 0 or 4,  those 2 values will never be 1.

To correct the issue, you want to make sure that whatever body you are checking is equal to the category you are looking for

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) == playerCategory && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & litCategory) == litCategory)
```

What this says is if the firstBody is a member of the category playerCategory and the secondBody is a member of litCategory,  then perform the following operatiion.

Below is the complete fix for your function:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody


    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

    }

    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) == playerCategory && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & litCategory) == litCategory)
    {
        lit.position.x = 400
        score += 1
    }
    else {
        gameOver()
    }

}
```